# pull a number From the record to the number

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, momentjs

how to pull a number out of day (columns in a day)
the date, but I need to display the records for a day (number)
doesn't help lenght
console.log(day.lenght) -> fake number sends
use mysql2

```
        const day = rows[1].createdAt + moment().startOf("day").toDate()
        const week = rows[0].createdAt + moment().startOf("week").toDate()
        const month = rows[0].createdAt + moment().startOf("month").toDate()
```

Comment: What is `rows`? Also, try `console.log(day.length)` - **not lenght**

Comment: @meropis, send 74 number. I don't have 74 entries.
if         `console.log(day);`  `Tue Sep 06 2022 16:12:07 GMT+0300 (Moscow default)1662411600000`

Comment: rows=>      `dbh.query('SELECT * FROM `table`', async (err, rows, fields) => {})`

Comment: So, did you try `day.length`? The reason you are seeing the number 74 is because the returned date string *is* 74 characters long - that number is correct

Comment: @meropis, yep, I get 74, but I have no records (2 records in the database)

Comment: So, there should be two elements in `rows` but there isnt? Is that your problem? Or, if there is two elements in rows, you can just a `forEach` to loop through and display the day. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @meropis, yes friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `map` function to return an array of dates from the `rows` array

```js
const day = rows.map(function(row) {
   return row.createdAt + moment().startOf("day").toDate();
});
```